# System.err does not show anything on Logcat and Console

Tags: android, logcat

I created a simple android applications, and added following to my mainActivity, I can run the application in emulator but just Device disconnected error will be shown on Logcat.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SqliteHelper db = new SqliteHelper(this,null);

            /**
             * CRUD Operations
             * */
            // add Books
            db.addBook(new Book("Android Application Development Cookbook"));  
            db.addBook(new Book("Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide"));      
            db.addBook(new Book("Learn Android App Development"));
            System.err.println("Adding records to DB!");
            Book book = db.getBook(1);
            System.err.println(">>" + book);
            Log.v(ALARM_SERVICE, book.getName());
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eclipse and you have 2 devices, for e.g. real device and emulator or more emulators, try to show view Devices (Eclipse Window->Show view->Other->Android->Devices) and then click on desired device to refresh logcat. This error might happen for e.g. if you are watching logs from one device and then disconnect it, but you don't switch to another one in Devices view.